# Cant display comments from a group using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I been trying to get every post from a facebook group with graph api, then show the posts and comments on a different webpage, my only problem is that I cant get the comments right, so far I have this:

```
<div class="post">
    <?foreach($data2->data as $d2) {?> 
    <div class="single">
        <div class="text">
            <span class="span_post" style="color: #999999; clear:both; display:block;"><?=$d2->message?></span>
            <?foreach($d2->comments->comment_list as $c2)?>
                <span class="span_comment" style="color: #999999; clear:both; display:block;"><?=print_r($c2->text) ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?}?>
</div>
```

data2 is defined as

```
$comment2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select%20message,%20comments%20from%20stream%20where%20source_id%20=%20{$group_id}&access_token={acces_token}";
$data2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($comment2));
```

Now the problem is that it only shows on comment, even if there are more than one comments (so if there are 10 comments, it shows the latests comment, without showing the other 10 even if they exist in the requested json).
I am pretty new to PHP, so maybe I did something wrong that is why I cant get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a graph request for this instead a FQL request.

Try requesting this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{GROUP_ID}?fields=feed&method=GET&format=json&access_token={ACESS_TOKEN}
```

To customize the request data. Use the Facebook Explorer Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer